# Конструктор возвращает null

Tags: c#, xamarin

Имеется следующий код:

```
var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
```

На второй строке после `new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);` объект становится null. С чем это может быть связано?

[image: Шаг 1]

[image: Шаг 2]

UPD: тоже самое происходит даже если написать так:

`ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] {0,1,0,1,0 } );`

Comment: Очень странно. Сделал тоже самое, но у меня корректно создался объект.
А какой тип файла вы используете? Может с ним что-то не так

Comment: @alladuh обычное изображение, месяца 2 назад код работал корректно. Были предприняты попытки унаследовать  HttpContent, результат тот же

Comment: Ваша dll точно совпадает с исходниками? Попробуйте пересобрать проект.

Comment: @Vlad пересобирал, чистил все в bin вручную, не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте вторым параметром размер массива поставить `upfilebytes.Length`

Comment: @NewView это тоже было сделано, все равно внутри метода вызывается стандартный конструктор, делал полностью такой же класс (https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/ByteArrayContent.cs), все происходит без ошибок, но после конструктора все равно null

Comment: Если делали такой-же класс, то пройтись по нему дебагером? Так-то ситуация загадочная :) похоже что библиотека не той версии в сборке чем при дизайне. В этом классе, что вы привели, смущает `readonly` у переменных.

Comment: А такой вызов: `ByteArrayContent (upfilebytes, 0, upfilebytes.Length);`

Comment: @NewView проходил дебагером, не помогает ни один из вызовов, переменные присваиваются, все проходит нормально, но после конструктора все равно null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выше находился другой блок try и catch, в котором объявлялась переменная с таким же именем, но типом StringContent. Это кажется странным, ведь тот блок имеет свою область видимости.

Upd:

Код был рабочим, была проблема в сервисе, видимо отладчик не мог переварить две переменные с одинаковым именем и отображал переменную из другой области видимости.

Comment: Для просмотра значения в отладчике надо всё же выполнить команду сначала, а судя по картинкам конструктор `ByteArrayContent` ещё не отработал (и переменная `content` не создалась), поэтому и видите другую переменную.

Comment: @älёxölüt если посмотреть 2 изображение, то можно заметить, что в данный момент шаг отладки находится на строке с объявлением HttpClient, т.е. конструктор ByteArrayContent уже отработал

Comment: Разве? Я думал, треугольник слева как раз обозначает текущую выполняемую строку.